# Routing in Laravel 4 and MySQL query

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to write a `mySQL` statement that will fetch a row matching the `user_id` aswell as all of the other rows in the `DB`. Currently I am doing it like this, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to perform the `query` so that it occurs  in one single query?

```
Route::get('user/candles-mix/{user_id?}', function($user_id){
        $candles = DB::select('SELECT * FROM candles WHERE user_id = ? LIMIT 1', array($user_id));
        $candles2 = DB::select('SELECT * FROM candles');
        return Response::json(array($candles, $candles2));
    });
```

Comment: in your code i see `$candles` and `$candles2` whats difference?? thats Are similar

Comment: You could just run the `select * from candles` query, and filter its result by `user_id` using PHP. That would reduce it to one query. I don't think it's possible to get 2 result sets from a single query, which is what you're looking for.

Comment: Added my above comment as an answer, with an example

Answer (score 1):

You could just run the `select * from candles` query, and filter its result by user_id using PHP. This would reduce it to one query. I don't think it's possible to get 2 result sets from a single query, which is what you're looking for.

```
Route::get('user/candles-mix/{user_id?}', function($user_id){
    $allCandles = DB::select('SELECT * FROM candles');
    $userCandles = array_filter(function($candle) {
        return ($user_id == $candle['user_id']);
    });

    return Response::json(array($userCandles, $allCandles));
});
```